# How to retain scroll position after reloading the web-page too?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css

$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#addmedic").click(function(){

            sessionStorage.setItem("pos", $("div").scrollTop());

        });
 });

 



$(document).ready(function(){

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("pos") != "undefined") {

          $("div").scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem("pos"));

          }

});

I have used Javascript scrollTo and scrollBy function. But its not working

for me . I want to store the position of scroll so that I can get after
 loading the web page too.

Comment: If it is urgent, you shouldn't be posting it here.

Comment: If you have urgent requirements then why not you hire some employees for you?

Comment: You can store the position in the cookie or localStorage.

Comment: We could care less if it's an urgent matter. Add more details to your question because right now it's unclear with no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *its not working for me* tells us nothing.

Comment: This site is all about helping you fix what's not working. But you need to show that code. Otherwise it looks like you just want someone to do your work for you

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Store scroll position in cookie before leaving page, then in case of page redirect use that cookie for setting the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

at scroll you can take id of the element and store it in a variable. than
Use `focus()` for that with ID. It will work for you. handle null for that variable before you make focus on it.

this is good example

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
  }
});
```

Comment: i have tried with focus it going on that position means it is focusing there but after that again scroll come on top.

Comment: thanks for ur reply

Comment: Oh man than stop scroll up by e.preventdefault

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#addmedic").click(function(){
   //alert($("div").scrollTop() + " px 1");
   //alert($("div").scrollTop() + " px 2");
  sessionStorage.setItem("pos", $("div").scrollTop());
  }); 
    
});

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 if (sessionStorage.getItem("pos") != "undefined") {
  //  alert(sessionStorage.getItem("pos") + " px 3");
    $("div").scrollTop(1500);
   
    alert(sessionStorage.getItem("pos") + " px 4");
    }
   
});

</script>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

$("#addmedic").click(function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem("pos", $("div").scrollTop());
    }); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){ if (sessionStorage.getItem("pos") != "undefined") { $("div").scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem("pos")); } });

Comment: thanq Rishu sir , Please help me  like this i am storing and i am getting after loading . or during loading you can say. but scroll behaving its default nature and its going on top.